# power of positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If $0 < A $ , **what are sufficient conditions for**

$\forall r\in {\rm I\!R}$ , $A^r$

**is also positive definite matrix.**

Comment: What do you mean with, say, $A^{\textbf{-}\log(7)}$?

Comment: $A = UDU^*$  so,$A^{-log(7)} = UD^{-log(7)}U^*$

Comment: And what is, for instance, $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}^{\textbf{-}\log(7)}$?

Comment: @GitGud: For a nonsingular matrix $A$, the power $A^{\alpha}$ defined by $A^{\alpha}=\mathbb e^{\alpha \log(A)}$

Comment: @hadi.reisizadeh if that's the definition, then your statement is always true.  Any unitarily diagonalizable matrix with positive eigenvalues is automatically positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

for any nonsigular matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and for every $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, $A^{\alpha}$ is defined by $A^{\alpha}=\mathbb e^{\alpha \log(A)}$. For more details, you can see [Functions of matrices: theory and computation](http://bookfi.net/md5/B7C0C82FB46DB4F4979B376EA4DCA061) at Chapter $11$. By this definition, and using the fact that $(\mathbb e^X)^*=\mathbb e^{X^*}$ (For proof see [Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations: An elementary introduction](http://bookfi.net/md5/D17F629BB639EF9FB69CAA7E6C39DFB7) Proposition $2.3$) we get that $(A^{\alpha})^*=(\mathbb e^{\alpha \log(A)})^*=\mathbb e^{{(\alpha \log(A)})^*}=e^{\alpha (\log(A))^*}=e^{\alpha \log(A^*)}=(A^*)^{\alpha}$

> Theorem: A symmetric square  matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are $> 0$.
>   For proof see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwje4JXXtInLAhXMHxoKHfVtCjUQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.utah.edu%2F~davar%2Fmath6010%2F2011%2FSomeLinearAlgebra.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFfsXnExtXrSkCIh36qsHvP2SzDPg&sig2=kqC2teRHgZzmfdjoowZbaw) Theorem $5$.

Since $A$ is positive definite, So all of its eigenvalues are $> 0$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^r$ is an eigenvalue of $A^r$. Since $\lambda\gt 0$, thus $\lambda^r \gt 0$ and so, all of eigenvalues of $A^r$ are $> 0$ which means $A^r$ is positive definite.

Comment: If $A$ is Hermitian , why $A^r$ is also Hermitian ?

Comment: @hadi.reisizadeh by your definition, $A^r = U\Lambda U^*$ for some diagonal matrix (with positive diagonal entries) $\Lambda$.  What is $(A^r)^*$?